# Jest on React, test a prop is called

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have a component with a props that is an action called `changeReason()`

And then, I have a function called when I press a button. The function is:

```
const handleNext = React.useCallback(() => {
  if (!reason) {
    changeReason({
      code: defaultReason,
      value: defaultReason
    });
  }
```

}

I want to test that `changeReason()` prop is called, I'm trying to do a test like this:

```
const changeReason = jest.fn();

const rendered = render(
  <TransactionReason
    changeReason={changeReason}
    reason={null}
  />
);

// When some button is pressed...
const reasonNext = rendered.getByTestId('reasonButton');
// it must fire an event
fireEvent.press(reasonNext);

const FakeFun = jest.spyOn(rendered, 'changeReason');
expect(FakeFun).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

I'm getting:

```
Cannot spy the handleNext property because it is not a function; undefined given instead
```

How could I test that I'm calling that action?

Comment: Why would you need FakeFun (not to mention that there's no way how this can work with functional component)? You already have changeReason spy. Assert it.

Comment: Assert it? I'm reading about that

Comment: This means that it should be `expect(changeReason).toHaveBeenCalled()`.

Comment: wops, thanks! I got it